# How to create distinct numeric types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to define distinct numeric types, so that I can't mix them up by accident, like so:

```
let h = 0 as Height;
let w = 0 as Width;

// These shall panic
h === w;
h + w;

// These shall work
(h as number) === (w as number);
(h as number) + (w as number);
```

Type aliases do not work, as they are for convenience only, and are treated as the same type:

```
// This definition works but does not enforce type checking over just
// using 'number'
type Height = number;
type Width = number;
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Edit**: added requirement that `(h + w)` shall fail too

Comment: You can go with some crazy hack like `type Height = number & { __h: never } | { __h: never }; type Width = number & { __w: never } | { __w: never };`, but this will also prevent `h + h;`

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can assign the types as different number types is to mock an interface and assign an unique field to the interface.

```
interface IHeight { height: any }
interface IWidth { width: any }

declare type Width = number & IWidth;
declare type Height = number & IHeight;

let h = 0 as Height;
let w = 0 as Width;
```

Now you can't do `h = w` directly without casting it to number again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shane! It is very compelling, and strictly
speaking, it fully works for the question _as stated_. However, while
`h === w` fails the build, other operators, like `h + w` are allowed,
which limit the usefulness of this approach. I'd say that's a 50% solution,
definitely better then using `number`.

Comment: There is no way in typescript to restrict that behaviour as javascript allows all primitive types to be used by arithmetic operators. The only way you _might_ be able to do this is by using external linting programs and set a custom lint rule. [TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) allows for custom rules, you might be able to add a custom type to the addition operator rule in here.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your case, but I use classes to prevent accidental equivalence, for example with entity ids. I also use classes to encapsulate units - so this does both the type safety and also allows you to have a logical home for unit conversions.

```
class Width {
  constructor(private value: number) { }

  get pixels() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

class Height {
  constructor(private value: number) { }

  get pixels() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

This assumes you create the sizes with a standard unit. You can add additional property accessors to get the height back in different units (like CM, Inches, etc).

When you use `Width` and `Height` they are not compatible, so you can't mix them up:

```
function getArea(width: Width, height: Height) {
  return width.pixels * height.pixels;
}

// number not assignable to `Width`
getArea(3, 4);

// `Height` is not assignable to `Width`
getArea(new Height(2), new Width(4));

// `Width` is not assignable to `Height`
getArea(new Width(2), new Width(4));

// Ok
getArea(new Width(2), new Height(4));
```

In most cases, you'd be using this for end-to-end type safety (as if you create a `new Width(5)` on the fly... who is to say that the `5` is the width - so the error you are trying to prevent would still creep in). So in most cases you'd be getting the values from something that returns a `Width` or `Height` and it would prevent the classic... `obj.Heigl` number accidentally being passed as a height.

```
const sizes = new SizeProvider();

// No
getArea(sizes.Height, sizes.Width);

// Ok
getArea(sizes.Width, sizes.Height);
```

Comment: Thanks Fenton! I am looking for an alternative, because this also fails `a + b`, forcing one to use `a.pixel() + b.pixel()`, but if `a` and `b` were different types to begin with, we again lost type safety. (For example, they are properties of objects passed in.) So I feel like this approach has the same practical utility as the approach suggested by Shane, but I find the other approach a lot simpler.